# Rails locale fallbacks are not working in production env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale, fallback, rails-i18n

I have a rails 3.2 application.
It has 2 locales ko & en.
ko is the default but I want it to fallback to en if it's not available.
The fallback works in development env but not in production env.

```
[config/application.rb]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :ko
    config.i18n.fallbacks = [:en]

[config/environments/production.rb]
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true


[config/locales/en.yml]
  ttt: TTT

[config/locales/ko.yml]
  (ttt is not defined)


**In development console:**

I18n.locale #=> :ko
I18n.t("ttt") #=> "TTT" (Works fine)


**In production console:**

I18n.locale #=> :ko
I18n.t("ttt") #=> "translation missing: ko.ttt" (Not working)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I commented out config.i18n.fallbacks = true in config/environments/production.rb. Now it works. Probably, that's not what it seems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you comment out `config.i18n.fallbacks = true` in your **production** / **staging** environments it works as expected.

Comment: Explanation: Setting `fallbacks = true` will overwrite `fallbacks = [:en]` in the way that the `default_locale` is used as fallback (which is `ko` in the question rather than `en`).

Answer (score 3):

Even if this question/answer is quite old, I will let here what I found for my case (Rails 5.X). The settings should look like this in `application.rb`

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en

config.i18n.available_locales = %i(en de)
config.i18n.fallbacks = {
  de: :en
}
```

And with that, all the references to `config.i18n.fallbacks = true` should be removed from the different environments.

Comment: I think it was a really bad software design choice to have `fallbacks` be a config variable that can be a `boolean`, `Hash`, `Array` and more. Using a Hash as @Cris R says is best.